# How do i call an Electron Browser Window multiple times?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an electron browser program that will allow the user to open multiple browser windows using a different proxy on each one. Im wondering how to call the `newWindow()` Function multiple times. In my current code it opens all the windows but only one loads up the page as shown in this picture
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnYkL.png)

Here is my code:

````
const url = require('url');
const async = require('async')

let win = null


function boot() {
  console.log(process.type)
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    resizable: false,
    frame: false
  })
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)


}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function newWindow() {
  var proxyList = '196.19.218.117:9044:dailyf:proxies'
  var siteUrl = 'https://twitter.com/home'

  win2 = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 750,
    height: 500,
    resizable: false,
    parent: win,
  })
  win2.webContents.session.setProxy({proxyRules:`http=foopy,direct://${proxyList}`}, function () {
  win2.loadURL(`${siteUrl}`);
  },

  win2.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  }),
)}

app.on('ready', boot)

function spawnChildren() {
  app.on('ready', _ => {
    console.log('yessirski')
    newWindow();
    sleep(4000)
    newWindow();
    sleep(4000)
    newWindow();
  }) 
}

spawnChildren();```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a local variable declaration for `win2`:

`var win2 = new BrowserWindow(){`

Otherwise, `win2` will be overwritten with the next call to `newWindow()` and only the last one will be usable.
(With no `var` local declaration, your variable will be global)